# A Python Program Adding Binary Exactly Like Humans

Tags: python, binary

Does anyone know a program like this for me to look at?

I need some help and would like to see an example of a written program.

It just needs to add binary digits exactly like humans do. So adds the numbers inputted in, and uses carries, etc, exactly how we do on paper.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Do you want an idiomatic solution heavily using the python standard library or an ad-hock solution easier for a beginner to understand because it doesn't require looking up the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

To create a binary variable you would do prefix it with 0b, like so. `0b01101` or `x = 0b01101`.
To add them together you wold do the same as any other var.

```
a = 0b01101
b = 0b10100

print(a + b) # etc
```

You can also find the binary representation of a number using the **bin** function.

```
>>> bin(2)
0b10
```

Comment: There is no such thing as binary variables or even binary type in python (unless you count bool). What you are doing is creating two regular integers using a binary form of the integer literal.

Comment: Also: the OP didn't ask to show him how to add two regular integers up in python nor did he ask how to convert an integer into a base-2 string representation, he asked for a program that **illustrates** the operation of binary addition.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an ad-hock solution to the problem (tested on python3; [execute online](https://ideone.com/hsBGVU))

```
def add(num1, num2):
    carry = 0
    result = [0] * (1 + max(len(num1), len(num2)))
    for i in range(len(result)):
        if 0 <= i < len(num1):
            digit1 = num1[-i - 1]
        else:
            digit1 = 0
        if 0 <= i < len(num2):
            digit2 = num2[-i - 1]
        else:
            digit2 = 0
        result[-i - 1] = (digit1 + digit2 + carry) % 2
        if digit1 + digit2 + carry > 1:
            carry = 1
        else:
            carry = 0
    return result
```

The function takes two lists of integers that can only be 0 or 1. For example:

```
add([1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1])
```

Adds numbers 5 (101 binary) and 7 (111 binary). It could be improved by adding code that would remove leading zeroes. You will probably also need to add code to input and output binary numbers nicely.

Note: this code can be made a lot more concise but then understanding it would require more knowledge of python. I might add a more concise version latter.